# Can you control the speed of a video clip playing in Quartz Composer?

Tags: video, interpolation, playback, quartz-composer, finalcut

Is there a way to manipulate the speed of the video playback? I'm especially interested in a way to slow down with frame blending, exactly like the function in Final Cut Pro.

Answer (score 5):

Currently it's not possible to do frame-blending using the built-in `Movie Loader` patch.

You *can* arbitrarily control the playback head, though.

- Insert a `Movie Loader` patch, and set the `Movie Location`.
- Connect it to a `Billboard`.  The movie should play at normal speed.
- Right-click on the patch, select `Timebase`, and then select `External`.  This gives the `Movie Loader` patch a `Patch Time` input, and freezes it at the first frame.

  - The value you enter for `Patch Time` is the time offset, in seconds, at which the `Movie Loader` should render.
- Insert a `Patch Time` patch, and connect its output to the `Movie Loader`'s `Patch Time` input.  The movie should again play at normal speed.

Now comes the fun part:

- Insert a `Mathematical Expression` patch and enter `t/2` for the equation.
- Connect the `Patch Time` patch to the input of the `Mathematical Expression`, and the output of the `Mathematical Expression` to the `Patch Time` input of the `Movie Loader` patch --- the movie now plays at half speed.

You can alter the equation to change the playback rate --- `t/3` will play at 1/3 speed, `t*2` will play at double speed, and so forth.

**However**, if you change the playback rate equation while the movie's playing, you'll notice that the playback head jumps to a new position rather than continuing on from the previous time.

To solve this, you'll want to use the `Integrator` patch.

- Create an `Integrator`, set the `Value` to `1`, and connect the `Integrator`'s output to the `Movie Loader`'s `Patch Time` input.  The movie should play from the beginning at normal speed.
- Change the `Integrator`'s `Value` to `0.5`.  The movie should play at half speed, continuing from the current position.

You can even play movies backwards using this technique (though, depending on what codec you use, it may severely impact performance).

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation should be able to help you. There's an example included with Quartz Composer (Interpolation Modes.qtz) and a beginning tutorial [here](http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2006/03/23/quartz-composer.html) that breifly mentions it (step 5).
[this wiki article](http://www.quartzcompositions.com/phpBB2/mediawiki/index.php/Interpolation) also discusses it and talks about the different types.

Note: I don't actually have a Mac that can run QC, so this is just what I've been able to find through Google, but it sounds like it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't quite what I'm looking for. I did find a clue though, by right clicking on the movie (the Movie Loader), I can change the time base to external. That gives me a "patch time" to edit, and I think the integers indicate frame numbers.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't more helpful, but I'm glad to hear it helped you find a clue.

Answer (score 0):

[v002 Movie Player (Beta)](http://v002.info/?page_id=13) as a replacement for the built-in Movie Loader patch provides a `Rate` input. I have gotten very smooth video speed changes with that.

[image: v002 Movie Player]

(I added the `Playhead Seconds` input; if anybody else would find that useful I'll post it.)